Google Play console integration with Service Account for fetching reports
We have an android app that we want to retrieve reports for , programatically from google play console.
For the purpose in Google Cloud Console we created a project to which we created** a Service Account** and invited it to Google Play Console as user. The role set is Editor.
Google Analytics API
Analytics Reporting API
Google Cloud API
All enabled. But probraatically we are still unable to fethc data for the statistics reports.
We have created the api key for the service account , .json file and and all other data necesarry is provided to the developer.
We have copied to Cloud Storage Path URI from Google PLay console -> Download Reports - > Statistics  for the Installs report.
But the request is returning that there are no buckets. Buckets Array is empty .
So do we need to buy Storage in Google Cloud Console and create a Bucket ?
If we create a Bucket how to assign it to the Google Play Console reports ?
The
gs://pubsite_prod_123456789/stats/installs/

is for example the Cloud Storage Path URI in Google Play . So if there is already a link for that bucket can we just enable the option to fetch from it or to assign it to a project in Google Cloud Console.

created a project - This does not help anyone to solve the problem. Please add some code to this post with describing where you are facing issues.

I do not have access to the code. An external developer is handling it, but i do not think code is needed here.
More so , if i create a Service Account , should i see it in Google Play Console - Linked Services?
Or have i missed something from the steps that need to be done in Google Cloud Console, where just the invite of that service account email as user in Google Play is enough
